# Is it possible to kill a program without access to htop and the likes?

Tags: linux, gnome, kill

Just now I opened a game which launched directly to black screen. I could hear the music in the background and see when I moved the cursor, but I couldn't `Alt+Tab` nor `Alt+F4`. I wanted to try `Alt+F2` and type reboot but I before I got that far, I got thrown out of the session and asked to log in again. I'm using GNOME 40.

What I am looking for is: after logging in, if a fullscreen program opens up to a black screen where you can only see the cursor, how do I kill the program if I can't Alt+Tab, Alt+F4 or open other programs?

Comment: That's what the `kill` command does. But you do need to be logged in somehow with a command line session

Comment: Yes, I know. What I am looking for is: after logging in, if a fullscreen program opens up to a black screen where you can only see the cursor, how do I kill the program if I can't `Alt+Tab`, `Alt+F4` or open other programs?

Comment: Can I create a hotkey combination that will kill the program in focus?

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd>, some function key). You should be presented with a console login screen.
- Login using the user you started the game.
- To be on the safe side, type `pgrep -l {nameOfGame}`. The output will be the name of the game plus the PID. If not, try less characters of the name.
- execute `pkill {nameOfGame}`. If it's not killed, try the same command using `sudo` or login with root user on the 2nd step.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F7</kbd>, usually it's either the first or the last vty) to return to the graphic environment. Since the game is killed, you should be able to view your desktop again.

---

Some hyper modern distros may not allow console login; I hope yours is not one of these. Perhaps `Wayland` enabled ones? If someone has any knowledge about it please do comment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm using fedora (X11 due to Nvidia) and I was thinking about making a hotkey combination that executes `xkill` but tbh I wanted something that kills only the program in focus instead of the whole server.

Comment: @telometto The commands I sent you do not kill the X server, only the program. I'll amend the answer on how to return to the graphic environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a command line you can use this command to list all the proceesses owned by the current user (you):

```
ps -fu $USER
```

The second column is the `PID` that uniquely identifies each process. You can then use this command to kill it (replace `{PID}` with the number)

```
kill {PID}
```

If that doesn't work, try these two, in order of increasing severity

```
kill -HUP {PID}
kill -KILL {PID}
```

The last one will always work, but I would strongly recommen you don't just start with it because you won't give the targeted process any opportunity to tidy up and close down neatly.

If you don't have a command line then the venerable `xkill` (from the Fedora package `xorg-x11-apps` will allow you to kill an X program with point and click. You just need some way to start it (a hotkey combination, or whatever).

Comment: Oh, I thought `xkill` killed the whole server lol! I can probably try that, then. Cheers

Comment: `man xkill` would help you identify what it does

Answer (score 0):

## Found a solution. All credit goes to [Kamil](https://superuser.com/users/56994/kamil-slowikowski)! Taken from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/757160/kill-the-currently-active-window-with-a-keyboard-shortcut).

Use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool) to kill the currently active window:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill
```

On Ubuntu, make a keyboard shortcut:

1. Open Keyboard settings (shown below).
2. Create a shortcut with the command: `xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill`

I chose: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

This shortcut will kill the currently active window *immediately*. It will *not* wait for the application to respond, terminate, save, close files, finish up, etc.

[image: Keyboard Settings]